# Spring + Hibernate show_sql not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to export the generated SQL query to the console using log4j. Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 are used.

The servlet-context.xml:

```
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
</session-factory>
```

When I call the following method, no infomation is generated at the console:

```
List<Comment> listComment = (List<Comment>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Comment.class).list();
```

Any suggestions?

==============================%================================

I think the problem is in the log4j.xml file. BTW, I am using the Spring MVC project of STS. Spring 4.3.2 + Hibernate 4.2.5 + Tomcat 8.0 + log4j 1.2.15.

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernage.SQL">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

The log generated by Hibernate is:

```
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/E:/OneDrive/PostDoc/SuperDr/Code/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CancerCloud/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 2663 ms
```

Even 'sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria' does not generate any SQL statement.

Is there anything I should add to the log4j.xml?

Comment: Are you using any Log4j configuration file.. like with  an xml file where you specify _category_ and _level_ of loggining??

Comment: @VirajNalawade I am not using any 'log4j.properties' file. I am quite sure log4j is working because I can use 'logger.info("Welcome");'.

Comment: according to my knowledge there *has to be* some log4j.properties or some config file.. or else how do you tell which files to redirect what messages to be shown in which log file..??

Comment: You should add :
`log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE`
to your log4j.properties

Comment: Which app server are you running under?

Comment: Which version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: @Ralph Using hibernate 4.3.5.Final

Comment: @Will Spring 4.2.3 + Hibernate 4.3.5 + log4j 1.2.15 + Tomcat 8.0

Comment: @VirajNalawade Using 'logger.info' I can send information to the console, so I guess log4j has already been configured by 'Spring MVC Project' of 'STS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got everything to work by changing

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

into

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="all" />
</logger>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your config: `org.hibernage.SQL` rather than `org.hibernate.SQL`.  This should be set at `debug` level.  No need to set the org.hibernate level to `all` as this will be rather spammy.

Comment: Great, that worked form me. To reduce the output, I switched to level "debug". That works too, but does not show all the senseless trace logs.

Comment: Do not try that if you are senstive! It's scary to see all the queries hibernate makes.

Answer (score -1):

> Upto my Knowledge, this could be the configuration,

```
<session-factory>

   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

   <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

- See more at: [Netbeans Link](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/DVDStoreEE6/src/java/hibernate.cfg.xml#sthash.n6CE1nC8.dpuf)